# True statement on custom object does not pass?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a simple custom class that holds just two coordinates.

```
public static class CoordPoint
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public CoordPoint(){ }

        public CoordPoint(int X, int Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
    }
```

When i have two equals of these objects to compare it does not pass the following statement.

```
CoordPoint curPosition = new CoordPoint(5,5);
CoordPoint destination = new CoordPoint(5,5);

if (curPosition.equals(destination))
{
    //This does not run
}
```

How am i supposed to evaluate my custom object?

Comment: Have you overridden the `equals` method? If not, do it. Your IDE can probably auto-generate the code if need be.

Comment: You are comparing an object with object, which isn't possible, you need to compare the parameters within the objects, so i suggest you have getX() and getY() in your code

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb I can understand why, but in my case it's only logical to compare the complete object. Isn't there a more straighforward way to do this with java?

Comment: @MennoGouw the first answer does exactly what you want it to do, you want to compare what is IN the object, not the object itself, so you would be comparing the whole object by comparing its inner parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `equals()` method in your class for proper comparison to take place. At the moment, if you don't override it, `equals()` for your class behaves the same way as the `==` operator. It's as if you had written this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
   return this == other;
}
```

In your case, this isn't good. What this does is return `true` only if the *references* you're comparing are the same. So, your code:

```
CoordPoint curPosition = new CoordPoint(5, 5);
CoordPoint destination = new CoordPoint(5, 5);

if(curPosition.equals(destination)) {
    /* This won't be executed, since even though the objects have the same member
     * values, the two references aren't pointing to the same object.
     */
}

CoordPoint anotherOne = curPosition;

if(curPosition.equals(anotherOne)) {
    // This will be executed, since the two references point to the same object.
}
```

wouln't work the way you intended. One way to correctly implement this method would be:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
   if(other == null) return false;
   if(!(other instanceof CoordPoint)) return false;
   CoordPoint otherPoint = (CoordPoint) other;
   return (this.X == otherPoint.X) && (this.Y == otherPoint.Y);
}
```

The check in the first line is important; otherwise, every time `other` was null you would get a NullPointerException in the line where you return the result when you tried to access a member of `other`.

Answer (score 3):

What you really should do is *override* (not overload) equals.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(! (o instanceof CoordPoint)) return false;
    CoordPoint p = (CoordPoint) o;
    return X == p.X && Y == p.Y;
}
```

Also, a stylistic heads up: fields should be camel case, so instead of

```
public class CoordPoint{
    private int X; //Capital letter X is weird here
    private int Y; //Here as well
    ...
}
```

It would be better to do

```
public class CoordPoint{
    private int x; //Much better
    private int y; // :)
    ...
}
```

Comment: I fixed it, but without @Override, it is a static class. I wanted it to belong to my Map class, a static class fixed that. Maybe i should move it to it's own file. I come from C# and like to have multiple classes inside files in these cases.

Comment: There's no reason (to my knowledge) that you can't override a method in a static class.. Also, the @Override annotation doesn't do anything as far as the code is concerned (though it does create an error if the method doesn't override anything, so I always use it). So if you're having trouble with that you can just remove the annotation. The fact that you're having an issue with it is weird though.

Answer (score 2):

You should override the `equals(Object o)` method of the Object class. Since all classes extend from `Object` they inherit this equals method, but it can sometimes be a good idea to override this method for your custom class.

If I were you, I would do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
   if(!(o instanceof CoordPoint)) // If you're comparing an object that isn't even of the right type, return false.
      return false;
   else{ // Otherwise, convert o to your object and compare on whatever you want. You may want to compare x and y.
      CoordPoint p = (CoordPoint) o;
      if(this.x == o.x && this.y == o.y)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }
}
```

I would not recommend creating an `equals(CoordPoint p)` method, because then you are not actually overriding equals. This way, you're using the same equals method, so it can be called in the same way.

Comment: @Radiodef changed it. As a former java guy who now works in a C# shop, it most definitely resembled C#.

Comment: @radiodef man, my syntax really need a refresher. I was surprised I even remembered how to properly override the equals method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your own implementation of equals. Something like this:

```
public boolean equals(CoordPoint a)
{
   return this.x == a.x && this.y == a.y;
}
```

If you dont do that you will end up comparing the two references of objects. which in this case are different since both references point to two different objects in the Java Heap

Comment: Look at your method signature. Don't you need a return type?

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @AntonH, the best way would be to override `equals()`.

Easy way would be...

EDIT also checked for null object

```
public boolean coordEquals(CoordPoint cp)
{

    boolean b = false;

    if(cp !=  null && this.x == cp.x && this.y == cp.y)
    {

         b = true;

    }

    return b;

}
```

Comment: You have also pictured an overload of `equals`.

Comment: It's not an overload now -- it's an entirely different method, which violates the established .equals() convention. Think about this from the perspective of someone unfamiliar to your class: that person would expect .equals(otherInstanceOfClass), not .coordEquals(otherInstanceOfClass)